# Use sed to edit a user in /etc/passwd

Tags: shell, sed

I am new to using sed command. My file looks something like this and I want to edit the last line i.e I want to add `saned:x:114:20000::/bin/tcsh` instead of `saned:x:114:20000::/home/saned`.

My `/etc/passwd` file looks like this:

```
speech-dispatcher:x:108:29:Speech Dispatcher,,,:/var/run/speech-dispatcher:/bin/sh
colord:x:109:117:colord colour management daemon,,,:/var/lib/colord:/bin/false
saned:x:114:20000::/home/saned
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to edit it using vipw?

Comment: What did you try and what happened?

Comment: `usermod -m -d /bin/tcsh saned` seems like a better approach. If you do want to use `sed`, then something like `sed /^saned/s/\/home\/saned$/\/bin/\/tcsh/' /etc/passwd` should work.